# Django Makemigrations returns ModuleNotFoundError: with module name suffixed by 'django'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I've been following the Python Crash Course 2e tutorial. I encountered a problem with makemigrations function from Django chapter(18). I created first app using startapp, and then tried to call makemigrations. It returns ModuleNotFoundError but it gives an app name suffixed by 'django'.
What I did was:

```
python -m venv ll_env
ll_env\Scripts\activate
pip install django (installed asgiref-3.2.3 django-3.0.3 pytz-2019.3 sqlparse-0.3.1)
django-admin startproject learning_log .
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver
```

This part runs smoothly, webserver works, everything is great.
Then I opened another terminal(on project level), and typed:

```
ll_env\Scripts\activate
python manage.py startapp learning_logs
<edited settings.py to include 'learning_logs'>
python manage.py makemigrations learning_logs
```

As a result makemigrations returns this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\djangoproj\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\djangoproj\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\djangoproj\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\djangoproj\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\djangoproj\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'learning_logsdjango'
```

settings.py include my module:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'learning_logs'
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

My directory is:

```
projectFolder/
    learning_log/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    learning_logs/
        migrations/
            __init__.py
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
    ll_env/
        include/
        Lib/
        Scripts/
    venv/
    db.sqlite3
    manage.py
```

I am running on Windows 10 x64, Pycharm Community 2019.2.3, Python 3.8.

What I tried:
1) changing the name
2) installing a previous version of django (2.2.11)
3) calling 'makemigrations' instead of 'makemigrations learning_logs'

I will appreciate any help, as I am quite confused with this.

Comment: I can't check whether this is the only cause of your issue, but in your ```INSTALLED_APPS``` you are missing a comma (,) after the first entry ('learning_logs')

Comment: Ehh... Thank you very much. I knew this was something easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because django doesn't recognize that you are trying to make a reusable app, if you aren't trying to make a reusable app, then just remove your app name from the list, otherwise, I'd take another look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/reusable-apps/

also, as a comment mentions, you are missing a `,` after your app name in the list

Comment: Thanks, this was overlooked coma issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the following:

```
    python manage.py makemigrations
    python manage.py migrate
```